# dynamically adding the multiple selected value and calculating the total

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':checkbox').change(function() {          
        $('input:checkbox:checked').filter(function() { 
            var sum = 0;           
            var Something = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text()) + sum;
            var value = Something;
            alert(Something);
            $('#total').html(value);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="echotable"> 
    <tr>
        <th class="field-label col-xs-1 primary">ID</th>
        <th class="field-label col-xs-5 primary">Name Of Service</th>
        <th class="field-label col-xs-3 primary">Price</th>
        <th class="field-label col-xs-3 primary">Total</th>
   </tr>
   <?php foreach($echo_details as $post){?>
        <tr class="active" id="myrow">
            <td class="field-label col-xs-1 primary"><?php echo $post->echo_id;?></td>
            <td class="field-label col-xs-5 primary"><?php echo $post->echo_scan;?></td>      
            <td class="field-label col-xs-3 primary" id="price"><?php echo $post->price;?></td>
            <td class="field-label col-xs-3 primary"><input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox"  /></td>
        </tr>
    <?php }?>  
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="total"><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
        <td id="total"></td>
    </tr>
```

I am dynamically getting the values from a database. When the user selects the multiple checkbox I am getting all the price values. Now I need to add all the price values and need to display in total cost. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: The HTML in your `foreach` loop is creating multiple elements with the same `id` attributes, which is making your HTML invalid. You should change `price` and `myCheckbox` to use classes instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic isn't quite correct. You need to use `each()` to loop over the checkboxes, not `filter()`. You will also need to define `sum` outside of the loop and add to it within each iteration before setting the `html()` of the 'total' `td` when the loop ends. Finally note that you set a `class` on the total `td` element, not an `id`, so you should use `.total` not `#total` to select it. Try this:

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    sum += parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text());
  });
  $('.total').html(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name Of Service</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Echo</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Fetal Echo</td>
    <td>1500</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">TOTAL</td>
    <td class="total">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```